# Multiple POSTs with jQuery and AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, drag-and-drop

I'm having an issue with posting data via AJAX through a drag and drop interface.  The data indeed is hitting my POST URL as defined, however, each and every time, the POST hits twice thereby causing the processing URL to handle the data again.

The premise of my application (at least this piece of it) was starting by basically using the code found at http://jsfiddle.net/UjQVw/2/ and to modify it for my needs.

I needed to have a container of items (in this case names) that were draggable to a user-defined number of divs on the opposite side of the screen -- whereby making 'room assignments' with a list of people.

Everything, except for the double POST is working well.  If anyone can assist, I'd be most appreciative!

**SAMPLE HTML CODE:**

```
<div class="parent_list">
    <h1>Registrants</h1>
    <ul id="unplaced" class="group">
        <?
        foreach ($obj->function as $key => $value)
        {
            ?>
            <li data-group-id="0" data-post-id="<?=$value["rmid"]?>">
                <?=$value["lname"]?>, <?=$value["fname"]?>
            </li>
            <?
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="lists">
    <h1>Rooms</h1>
    <ul style="display:none" id="new_list" class="group"></ul>
</div>

<input type="button" id='add' value="+ Add Room"/>
```

**SAMPLE JS**

```
<script>
    var count = 0;
    $("#add").click(function() {
        count++;
        var $clone = $("#new_list").clone();
        $clone.attr({
            id: count,
            style: "" // remove "display:none"
        });
        $clone.find(".group").each(function(){
            $(this).attr({
                id: $(this).attr("id") + count
            });
        });
        $(".lists").append($clone);
        $('.group').sortable({
            connectWith: '.group',
            update: function(event, ui) {
                var lodging = new Array();
                $('.group li').each(function(i) {
                    var id = $(this).attr('data-post-id');
                    var group = $(this).parent().attr('id');
                    lodging.push(group+'_'+id);
                });
                console.log(event);
                $.ajax({ 
                    type    : "POST",
                    cache   : false,
                    url     : 'lodging_process.php',
                    data: {
                        'lodging[]': lodging
                    },
                 });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the response by @John, I did some more testing and looking around and found this gem that's apparently stumped several others by me.  As stated in the original question, the POST was indeed working...it was simply posting TWICE after each event.  The reason for this is that there were changes in BOTH lists, thereby initiating the callback for EACH list that's affected.

Adding this simple if check as outlined here:  https://forum.jquery.com/topic/sortables-update-callback-and-connectwith

```
update:function(e,ui) {
    if (this === ui.item.parent()[0]) {
        //your code here
    }
}
```

has done the trick for me.  Hope this information helps others with multiple callbacks using jQuery sortable and connectWith functions.

So...the new JS looks like this:

```
<script>
    var count = 0;
    $("#add").click(function() {
        count++;
        var $clone = $("#new_list").clone();
        $clone.attr({
            id: count,
            style: "" // remove "display:none"
        });
        $clone.find(".group").each(function(){
            $(this).attr({
                id: $(this).attr("id") + count
            });
        });
        $(".lists").append($clone);
        $('.group').sortable({
            connectWith: '.group',
            update: function(event, ui) {
                if (this == ui.item.parent()[0]) {
                    var lodging = new Array();
                    $('.group li').each(function(i) {
                        var id = $(this).attr('data-post-id');
                        var group = $(this).parent().attr('id');
                        lodging.push(group+'_'+id);
                    });
                    $.ajax({ 
                        type    : "POST",
                        cache   : false,
                        url     : 'lodging_process.php',
                        data: {
                            'lodging[]': lodging
                        },
                     });
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always buffer it with a boolean.

```
<script>
    var sending = false;  //Buffering variable

    var count = 0;
    $("#add").click(function() {
        count++;
        var $clone = $("#new_list").clone();
        $clone.attr({
            id: count,
            style: "" // remove "display:none"
        });
        $clone.find(".group").each(function(){
            $(this).attr({
                id: $(this).attr("id") + count
            });
        });
        $(".lists").append($clone);
        $('.group').sortable({
            connectWith: '.group',
            update: function(event, ui) {
                var lodging = new Array();
                $('.group li').each(function(i) {
                    var id = $(this).attr('data-post-id');
                    var group = $(this).parent().attr('id');
                    lodging.push(group+'_'+id);
                });
                console.log(event);
                if(!sending) {  //Make sure we are not already sending a request
                    sending = true;
                    $.ajax({ 
                        type    : "POST",
                        cache   : false,
                        url     : 'lodging_process.php',
                        data: {
                            'lodging[]': lodging
                        },
                        success: {
                            sending = false; //Upon finishing, allow another ajax command of this type
                        },
                        error: {
                            sending = false;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

See if that works.

Comment: @john - thanks for the assist here.  Although this wasn't what I was looking for to solve my issue, it was a good thing to add to my limited knowledge of jQuery.  After receiving your response and testing it a bit, my search patterns took on a different approach thereby leading me to the solution I came up with.  (See below).

Comment: @jkitz I thought it might be something like that.  I made a jsfiddle, but I wasn't able to replicate the event firing twice.  For future reference, the `event` parameter given in the `update` function will usually tell you which target's action is triggering the event.  When an event fires multiple times, it probably means that either they are _two distinct events_, or you have _subscribed to the event two times_.

Comment: @jkitz In fact, I thought maybe you were subscribing two times.  If you click the `#add` HTML element a second time, it will execute the `$('.group').sortable({ ... })` method again. Normally this might be a problem because you are actually attaching the `update` function twice, but it looks like jQuery actually handles this for you (I tested this scenario).